# MySQL : Permanently getting " Waiting for table metadata lock"

Tags: mysql, process, blocking

My MySQL database serves three webapps as the storage backend. However I recently encounter permanantly the error "Waiting for table metadata lock". It happen nearly all the time and I do not understand why.

```
mysql> show processlist
    -> ;
+------+-----------+-----------------+------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id   | User      | Host            | db         | Command | Time | State                           | Info                                                                  |
+------+-----------+-----------------+------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   36 | root      | localhost:33444 | bookmaker2 | Sleep   |  139 |                                 | NULL                                                                  |
|   37 | root      | localhost:33445 | bookmaker2 | Sleep   |  139 |                                 | NULL                                                                  |
|   38 | root      | localhost:33446 | bookmaker2 | Sleep   |  139 |                                 | NULL                                                                  |
|   39 | root      | localhost:33447 | bookmaker2 | Sleep   |   49 |                                 | NULL                                                                  |
|   40 | root      | localhost:33448 | bookmaker2 | Sleep   |  139 |                                 | NULL                                                                  |
| 1315 | bookmaker | localhost:34869 | bookmaker  | Sleep   |   58 |                                 | NULL                                                                  |
| 1316 | root      | localhost:34874 | bookmaker3 | Sleep   |   56 |                                 | NULL                                                                  |
| 1395 | bookmaker | localhost:34953 | bookmaker  | Sleep   |   58 |                                 | NULL                                                                  |
| 1396 | root      | localhost:34954 | bookmaker3 | Sleep   |   46 |                                 | NULL                                                                  |
| 1398 | root      | localhost:34956 | bookmaker3 | Query   |   28 | Waiting for table metadata lock | CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LogEntries (lid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMEN |
| 1399 | root      | localhost       | NULL       | Query   |    0 | NULL                            | show processlist                                                      |
+------+-----------+-----------------+------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Of course one can kill the corresponding process. However if I restart my program that tries to create the table structure of my database "bookmaker3" the newly created process ends up again in a metalock.

I even cannot drop the database:

```
mysql> drop database bookmaker3;
```

This yields also a metalock.

How can this be repaired?

Comment: you could check here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148630/how-do-i-find-which-transaction-is-causing-a-waiting-for-table-metadata-lock-s

or here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462249/clear-transaction-deadlock

Answer (score 53):

The accepted solution is, unfortunately, *wrong*. It is right as far as it says,

> Kill the connection with lock

This is indeed (*almost* surely; see below) what to do. But then it suggests,

> ```
> Kill 1398
> ```

...and 1398 **is not** the connection with the lock. How could it be? 1398 is the connection *waiting* for the lock. This means it *does not yet have* the lock, and therefore, killing it avails nothing. The process holding the lock will still hold the lock, and the *next* thread trying to do something will therefore *also* stall and enter "Waiting for metadata lock" in due order.

You have no guarantee that the processes "waiting for metadata lock" (WFML) won't also block, but you can be certain that killing only WFML processes will achieve exactly **nothing**.

The real cause is that **another process is holding the lock**, and more importantly, `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` *will not tell you directly which it is*.

The one thing you can be sure of, it is **none** of the processes labeled "Waiting for metadata lock". Those are, so to speak, the *victims*.

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` **WILL** tell you if the process is *doing* something, yes. Usually it works. Here, the process holding the lock is doing *nothing*, and hides among other threads also doing nothing and reported as 'Sleeping'.

If `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` shows you a process running a DML, or in "Sending data" status, well then, *that* is almost certainly the culprit. The other processes are waiting for it to release the locks (they can be implicit locks; the process need not have issued a LOCK TABLE at all, that actually would lock *in a different way*). But a process can be holding a lock while it's doing nothing, and is duly marked as "Sleep".

In the OP's case the culprit is *almost certainly* process **1396**, which started before process 1398 and is now in `Sleep` state, and has been for 46 seconds. Since 1396 clearly did all that it needed to do (as proved by the fact that it is now sleeping, and has done so for 46 seconds, *as far as MySQL is concerned*), no thread having gone to sleep *before* it could have held a lock and be still holding it (or 1396 would also have stalled).

Due to MySQL's "deadlock-free" locking strategy, no process can hold a lock, release it, and resume it again; so a lock wait is invariably caused by a process still holding a lock and never having held *that* lock before. This is useful (we will make use of this fact below), because it guarantees that the lock "queue", so to speak, is *sequential*.

**IMPORTANT**: if you connected to MySQL as a limited user, `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` will **not** show all the processes. So the lock might be held by a process that you don't see.

So: if `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` shows you everything and shows one **running** process, then that process is probably responsible and you need wait for it to finish whatever it's doing (or you may kill it - at your peril).

The rest of this answer deals with the baffling case where processes are waiting **without an apparent reason** and no one seems to be doing anything.

## A better `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

```
SELECT ID, TIME, USER, HOST, DB, COMMAND, STATE, INFO
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE DB IS NOT NULL
    AND (`INFO` NOT LIKE '%INFORMATION_SCHEMA%' OR INFO IS NULL)
    ORDER BY `DB`, `TIME` DESC
```

The above can be tuned to show only the processes in SLEEP state, and anyway it will sort them by time descending, so it is easier to find the process that is hanging (due to sequentiality, it usually is the `Sleep`'ing one immediately before the ones "waiting for metadata lock"; and it will *always* be one of those that have slept more than any of those waiting).

## The important thing

Leave any "waiting for metadata lock" process *alone*.

## Quick and dirty solution, not really recommended but quick

Kill *all* processes in "Sleep" state, on the same database, that are **older than the oldest** thread in "waiting for metadata lock" state. This is what [Arnaud Amaury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caedite_eos._Novit_enim_Dominus_qui_sunt_eius.) would have done:

- for each database that has at least one thread in WaitingForMetadataLock:

  - the oldest connection in WFML on that DB turns out to be Z seconds old
  - ALL the "Sleep" threads on that DB and older than Z must go. Start with the freshest ones, just in case.
  - If one older and non-sleeping connection exists on that DB, then maybe that is the one holding the lock, *but it is doing something*. You may of course kill it, but especially if it is an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE, you do so at your own peril.
  - After each `KILL`, re-evaluate the situation and restart the process accordingly. Processes that were waiting might now be running, or they may have run briefly and be now sleeping. *They might even be the ones, now, holding a new metadata lock*.

Ninety-nine times out of one hundred, the thread to be killed is the **youngest** among those in Sleep state that are *older* than the older one waiting for metadata lock:

```
TIME     STATUS
319      Sleep
205      Sleep
 19      Sleep                      <--- one of these two "19"
 19      Sleep                      <--- and probably this one(*)
 15      Waiting for metadata lock  <--- oldest WFML
 15      Waiting for metadata lock
 14      Waiting for metadata lock
```

(*) the TIME order actually has milliseconds, or so I was told, it just doesn't show them. So while both processes have a Time value of 19, the lowest one ought to be younger.

## More focused fix

Run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and look at the "TRANSACTION" section. You will find, among others, something like

```
TRANSACTION 1701, ACTIVE 58 sec;2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1396, OS thread handle 0x7fd06d675700, query id 1138 hostname 1.2.3.4 whatever;
```

Now you check with `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` what is thread id 1396 doing with its #1701 transaction. Chances are it is in "Sleep" status. So: an active transaction (#1701) with an active lock, it has even done some changes as it has an undo log entry... but is currently idle. *That* and no other is the thread you need to kill. Losing those changes.

Remember that doing nothing in MySQL does not mean doing nothing in general. If you get some records from MySQL and build a CSV for FTP upload, during the FTP upload the MySQL connection is idle.

Actually if the process using MySQL and the MySQL server are on the same machine, that machine runs Linux, and you have root privileges, there's a way to find out which *process* has the connection that requested the lock. This in turn allows to determine (from CPU usage or, at worst, `strace -ff -p pid`) whether that process is *really* doing something or not, to help decide if it's safe to kill.

## Why does this happen?

I see this happening with webapps that use "persistent" or "pooled" MySQL connections, which nowadays usually save very little time: the webapp instance terminated, but **the connection did not**, so its lock is still alive... and blocking everyone else.

**Another interesting way** that I found is, in the hypotheses above, to run a query returning some rows, *and only retrieve some of them*. If the query is not set to "auto-clean" (however the underlying DBA does it), it will keep the connection open and prevent a full lock on the table from going through. I had this happen to me in a piece of code that verified whether a row existed by selecting that row and verifying whether it got an error (not exists) or not (it must exist), but *without actually retrieving the row*.

## PHP and PDO

PDO has persistent connection capability. This is how I ensure PDO does not pool connections and closes every one of them. It's messy.

When opening, set the options (fourth option to new PDO()):

```
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
```

When disconnecting:

```
// We should have no transactions and no locks.
// So we discard them.
try {
    $pdo->exec('ROLLBACK WORK');
    $pdo->exec('UNLOCK TABLES');
} catch (Exception $err) {
    // Send a mail
}
// No cooperative locks. So this will not hurt a bit.
try {
    $pdo->exec('DO RELEASE_ALL_LOCKS()');
} catch (Exception $err) {
    // Send a mail
}
// Ensure the connection withers on the vine, but not too soon.
$pdo->exec('SET wait_timeout = 5');

// $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 5);
// If nothing else works!
// try {
//     $pdo->exec('KILL CONNECTION_ID()');
// } catch (Exception $err) {
//     // Exception here is expected: "Query execution was interrupted"
// }
// Invoke the garbage collector
$pdo = NULL;
```

## Ask the DB

Another way to get the culprit if you have a recent MySQL, *but not too recent* since **this is going to be deprecated**, is (you need privileges again on the information schema)

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCKS 
     WHERE LOCK_TRX_ID IN 
        (SELECT BLOCKING_TRX_ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS);
```

## Actual solution, requiring time and work

The problem is usually caused by this architecture:

> ```
>  webapp (jar, php) --> container or app connection pool
>    (mysqldb, php_module, fastcgi...) --> 
>    --> MySQL
> ```

When the webapp dies, or the webapp lightweight thread instance dies, **the container/connection pool might not**. And it is *the container* that keeps the connection open, so obviously the connection does not close. Quite predictably, **MySQL does not consider the operation complete**.

If the webapp didn't clean after itself (no `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` for a transaction, no `UNLOCK TABLES`, etc.), then whatever that webapp started doing *is still extant*, and might still be blocking everyone else.

There are then two solutions. The worse one is to [lower the idle timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284194/terminating-idle-mysql-connections). But guess what happens if you wait too long between two queries (exactly: "MySQL server has gone away"). You could then use `mysql_ping` if available (soon to be deprecated. [There are workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244462/how-do-i-ping-the-mysql-db-and-reconnect-using-pdo) for PDO. *Or* you might check for *that* error, and reopen the connection if it happens (this is the Python way). So - for a small performance fee - it's doable.

The better, smarter solution is less straightforward to implement. Endeavour to have the script clean after itself, ensuring to retrieve all rows or free all query resources, catch all exception and deal with them properly, or, if possible, **skip persistent connections altogether**. Let each instance create its own connection or [use a smart pool driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209454/a-persistent-connection-with-jdbc-to-mysql) (in PHP PDO, use `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` explicitly set to `false`).

Alternatively (e.g. in PHP) you can have destruct and exception handlers force clean the connection by committing or rolling back transactions (this ought to be enough) and maybe even issuing explicit table unlocks and RELEASE_ALL_LOCKS(), or committing connection suicide (`KILL CONNECTION_ID()`) for good measure.

I do not know of a way of querying for extant resultset resources in order to free them; the only way would be to *save* those resources in a private array.

Comment: Very strange, I has a sleep proces that time kept changing, so it never looks liked it was henging just like it was re-creating, I however noticed the id didn't change so after killing that one it fixed the issue

Comment: @IllegalOperator If the time kept increasing that's normal - the thread had a lock, and it kept on sleeping. The big problem would be if the thread had a lock and the sleep time kept resetting to zero: that would mean that the thread is doing something, inside a badly borked transaction. I'd still recommend to kill, but whatever the thread was doing would be lost, and possibly left in an unstable state.

Comment: Thank you very muxh - that helped - and also very important - explains the situation very good. 
Nice answer!

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. Thanks @LSerni

Comment: When I get rid of connnection pool, or at least reduce the number of min_pool and max_pool (from min=10 & max=100) to min=1 & max=2 in my app. I'm not getting metadata lock anymore. 
This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

Kill the connection with lock

```
Kill 1398
```

Then check if you have autocommit set to 0 by

```
select @@autocommit;
```

If yes, you propably forgot to commit transaction. Then another connection want to do something with this table, which causes the lock.

In your case: If you made some query to *LogEntries* (which exists) and did not commit it, then you try to execute CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS from another connection - metadata lock happens.

**edit**
For me the bug is somewhere at your application. Check there, or set *autocommit to 1* if your not using transactions in application.

ps also check this posts:

- [not a bug on bugs.mysql](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61935)
- [replication of lock on MyISAM and
  INNOdb tables](http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=1189)

Comment: Right, I tried to create a table structure on the database while simultaneously having another connection. Shuting down the other connection solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is this:

1. Run this command and find out the owner thread ID which is holding the lock: `select * from performance_schema.metadata_locks;`
2. Find the PROCESSLIST_ID x for that particular thread from this command: `select * from performance_schema.threads;`
3. `Kill x;`

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have HS plugin and trying to `CREATE` or `ALTER` table which was already attempted to assess via HS you will face with similar problem and you have to restart HS plugin in this way to release table metadata lock:

```
UNINSTALL PLUGIN HANDLERSOCKET;
INSTALL PLUGIN HANDLERSOCKET SONAME 'handlersocket.so';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the modern MariaDB you can run the following to preserve the connection while at the same time clearing the blocking query

`sudo mysql -e "KILL QUERY ID XXXX"`

You can obtain the QUERY_ID by running the following:

`SELECT QUERY_ID FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID = XXXX;`

If you kill the process ID vs. the query ID, any script that you are running will loose it's connection and potentially cause downstream issues.

Answer (score 0):

so LSerni has answered this question wonderfully, but I thought I'd add something I wrote in PHP.

On my project we are building on a lot of legacy code. So modern ideas like connection pools aren't present. We have a lot of one-use connections to the DB being left to idle out. Unfortunately that means that my latest update which is altering a large table has been hanging.

I wrote this PHP function; I call it immediately *after* my `myqsli_query()` statement.

```
function unsleepingCity($link) {
    //to prevent the issue in https://www.abhinavbit.com/2019/07/sleep-thread-causing-waiting-for-table-metadata-lock.html
    //looks for sleep processes locking the DB and kills them
    $query = "SELECT ps.id from information_schema.processlist ps join information_schema.INNODB_TRX itx on itx.trx_mysql_thread_id=ps.id and ps.command='Sleep';";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $proc = $row['id'];
        $query="kill $proc;";
        mysqli_query($link,$query);
    }
}
```

It's a little scorched-earth, but very effective.

If you want to get more data in the query about those sleep processes, I also have this query for you:

`SELECT ps.id,ps.user,ps.host,ps.db,ps.command from information_schema.processlist ps join information_schema.INNODB_TRX itx on itx.trx_mysql_thread_id=ps.id and ps.command='Sleep';`