# How do I ping the MySQL db and reconnect using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using MySQL [PDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Development_and_community) for handling database querying and all. But most of the time, the MySQL connection is gone away. So I am looking in the PDO that will check if the db connection exists or not and if it does not exit, then I need to connect the database to continue the query execution.

I am new to the MySQL PDO. How should I handle this situation?

Comment: why not use `mysqli_ping()`, if its false then try to reconnect

Comment: @user1978142 how does mysqli_ping() help when he's using PDO?

Answer (score 11):

I tried to find a solution for the same problem and I found the following answer:

```
class NPDO {
    private $pdo;
    private $params;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->params = func_get_args();
        $this->init();
    }

    public function __call($name, array $args) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->pdo, $name), $args);
    }

    // The ping() will try to reconnect once if connection lost.
    public function ping() {
        try {
            $this->pdo->query('SELECT 1');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->init(); // Don't catch exception here, so that re-connect fail will throw exception
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function init() {
        $class = new ReflectionClass('PDO');
        $this->pdo = $class->newInstanceArgs($this->params);
    }
}
```

The full story is in *[Adding ping() function to PDO](https://terenceyim.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/adding-ping-function-to-pdo/)*.

Somebody else was thinking to use **PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS**, but he figured out that: "`$db->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS)` keeps replying “Localhost via UNIX socket” even after stopping mysqld".

Comment: Apparently 'DO 1;' is slightly shorter than SELECT 1 (in network transfer, as well as in response time)... i have not tried this myself yet.. but just wanted to share as an alternative...

Comment: I guess "DO 1" is the better method for this process, except if the function should verify the server really answers (but we are on a too high level api  for that)

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.6+, it'd be better to unpack your arguments over using  reflection, as explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat

$this->pdo = new \PDO(...$this->params);

Answer (score -3):

You can use like this:

```
# connect to the database
try {
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection error " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: The questions asks how to ping and reconnect not how to catch a connection error!

Comment: There is a reason why mysql_ping is depreciated. It is no longer the correct way to do it. This IS the correct way. Though he should have gone into more detail

Comment: mysql_ping is to check connection while script execution, not just after make the connection, in this way it's fully apreciated.