# Why PDO generates warnings when we tell it not to do it?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqlnd

**Problem**

We tell PDO to wrap each issue into exception.
In some cases it generates a few warnings and only then throws exception.

**Why** does it do it?

**Duplicates?**

There were no correct answers on SO regarding it. Last question was [PHP PDO Exception + Warning on MySQL Has Gone Away?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34098828/388929) but people just marked it as duplicate instead of carefully answer.

Accepted answer not answers why does it do it and when. So I researched and will answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of PDO could use mysqlnd driver, which not respects any of PDO's "convert-issues-to-extensions" policy.

Just look at [sources of mysqlnd driver](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=php_error_docref%20repo%3Aphp%2Fphp-src%20path%3A%2Fext%2Fmysqlnd&type=Code&ref=searchresults).

We clearly see there direct calls to `php_error_docref`.

And one of examples, shown at [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098828/php-pdo-exception-warning-on-mysql-has-gone-away) explained by these lines: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.5.31/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c#L35:L61

Answer (score 0):

Use set_error_handler() and restore_error_handler()

```
public function query($sql)
{
    $retries = 0;
    $result = null;

    while (true) {
        try {
            set_error_handler(function () {
            });
            $result = $this->pdo->query($sql);
            restore_error_handler();
            break;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            restore_error_handler();
            if (++$retries < self::RECONNECT_ATTEMPT) {
                if (strpos($e->getMessage(), 'server has gone away') !== false) {
                    $this->connect();
                    $this->getLogger()->info('Reconnect database, reason: server has gone away');
                }
            } else {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It's obvious. The question was about "why" it happens. Not how to cure it. Anyway it will help fot those who don't know it.