# Unable to access database after truncat table mysql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm unable to access my MySQL database after executing ***Truncat table*** via PHPmyadmin, below a picture of ***SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST*** command.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem with phpMyAdmin, but rather with whatever other application uses that table. It looks like phpMyAdmin is waiting for the other application to release a lock, which is probably caused by a transaction that hasn't been committed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19801381/2385479 suggests how one way to recover, and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/metadata-locking.html has more information about the message you see.